# React onClick without JSX

Tags: reactjs

I have a special application of React to get working where I would prefer not to use JSX and Where I need to monitor clicks on links outside of React. I can't seem to get an onClick event to fire. The code I have needs to render the link inactive for the page it's on.`

```
var LinkCell = React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        var attr = {
          "data-id":this.props.dataID,
          "href": this.props.href,
          "onClick": function(){return false}
        };
        var lnk = React.DOM.a(attr,this.props.href);

        return React.DOM.td({},lnk);
      }
    });
```

This doesn't work and the link goes to the URL in the href. Do I have to do this in JSX?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't firing? Because it [works for me](http://codepen.io/pen?editors=001). What do you expect `return false` to do?

Comment: It's nearly impossible for JSX and non-JSX code to function differently, since JSX is transpiled, not run directly by the browser. JSX *becomes* the code you are looking at.

Comment: Use `babe`l with the `react` preset to transpile to `js`

Comment: Returning false is supposed to keep the link from going to it's href, but because of the way React does events there was no way of putting an attribute in the tag which says onClick="return callbackfunction()". I needed to preventDefault() inside the function instead. 

@surfer190 as I said above I would prefer to not use JSX as this is an HTML settings panel used by an embedded web browser control. Trying to keep the code  I call in it down to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found the solution. As you may know if a callback returns false normally you have to put inside an onclick attribute

```
return mycallbackfunction();
```

with this code I had to use preventDefault();. I don't know why I didn't try it before but thanks for the replies.

```
var LinkCell = React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        var attr = {
          "data-id":this.props.dataID,
          "href": this.props.href,
          onClick:function(e){e.preventDefault();}
        };
        var lnk = React.DOM.a(attr,this.props.href);

        return React.DOM.td({},lnk);
      }
    });
```

Comment: React deprecated the ability to return false from event handlers in 0.12 and instead enforces the `event.preventDefault/stopPropagation` methodology.

Answer (score 0):

i found the best solution for this

```js
//like_button.js
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Click This'
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.getElementById('domContainer');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="domContainer"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="like_button.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're saying 'best solution'. Can you expand on why it's better than other solutions? Please edit your question and add some relevant detail.